# pointing sub domain to AWS EC2 server, website not displaying

Tags: networking, server, apache2, amazon-ec2, domain-server

The main domain is pointed on other AWS EC2 instance and due to the subdomain is a staging site so I launch another AWS EC2 instance, installed Apache, added the subdomain vhost to default `.conf` at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.maindomain.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.maindomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@maindomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain

    <Directory /var/www/html/subdomain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
        #Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.maindomain.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.maindomain.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Its been 24 hours already and website is not displaying at all

> This site can’t be reached subdomain.maindomain.com refused to
> connect.

and I ping the subdomain.maindomain.com and it giving me the correct AWS EC2 server IP. What could be wrong here? any help, suggestions, recommendations is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Server is AWS EC2 with ubuntu 20.4 OS

Comment: Just to confirm, you have a `.` before `com` in your `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` values, yes? Have you confirmed that the alias file is being read?

Comment: @matigo my mistake, it should be .com. I wrote it wrong. I updated my post.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache? `sudo service apache2 restart` will re-read all the configurations into memory. Alternatively, you may want to throw some wildcards on your `ServerAlias` to capture all traffic 

Comment: @matigo yes does several restarts with no luck

Comment: I was in the midst of writing an answer with a bunch of things to check when I noticed that you are redirecting to `https`, but there is no `*:443` configuration in the contents of the question. Do you have an Apache configuration file that is listening on port 443 and has a valid SSL certificate installed?

Comment: @matigo yes, theres ssl and port :443 but even removing the https and just http alone, still not able to display. I updated my post with just http